# Can't insert data into mongodb when using scrapy

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I follow a tutorial to insert data into the mongoldb,but when I use GUI to check mongodb, I notice that only the database and collection have been set up and the data haven't been inserted.
The Scrapy code:

```
  __author__ = 'Rabbit'
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy_Data.items import EPGD

class EPGD_spider(Spider):
    name = "EPGD"
    allowed_domains = ["epgd.biosino.org"]
    term = "man"
    start_urls = ["http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?textquery="+term+"&submit=Feeling+Lucky"]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')
    url_list = []
    base_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD"
    for site in sites:
        item = EPGD()
        item['genID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract())
        item['genID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
        item['taxID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract())
        item['taxID_url'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/@href').extract())
        item['familyID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract())
        item['familyID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
        item['chromosome'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract())
        item['symbol'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract())
        item['description'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract())
        yield item

    sel_tmp = Selector(response)
    link = sel_tmp.xpath('//span[@id="quickPage"]')

    for site in link:
        url_list.append(site.xpath('a/@href').extract())

    for i in range(len(url_list[0])):
        if cmp(url_list[0][i], "#") == 0:
            if i+1 < len(url_list[0]):
                print url_list[0][i+1]
                actual_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/"+ url_list[0][i+1]
                yield Request(actual_url, callback=self.parse)
                break
            else:
                print "The index is out of range!"
```

The settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy_Data.pipelines.EPGD_pipeline', ]

MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "EPGDdddd"
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "EPGD_test"
```

The pipeline.py

```
class EPGD_pipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
        settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']
    )
    db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
    self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    valid = True
    for data in item:
        if not data:
            valid = False
            raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
    if valid:
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
        settings['MONGODB_DB'],
        settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
        settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
    return item
```

The mongodb details:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe3t0.png)

Besides,when the crawl is running, I can get the printout in the terminal that `2016-03-29 15:04:04 [scrapy] INFO: Item wrote to MongoDB database EPGDdddd, collection EPGD_test, at host localhost, port 27017`
 But there are no data in the database

So I don't know how to solve this problem with all these efforts,can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the problem?! Do you want the data to be updated , too or what?

Comment: I just want to insert data into the mongo's collection,and it can't be inserted.After I do all these works, I can't find any datas in the collection

Comment: The most important thing is that  I can insert the data when using terminal, but I can't insert it in scrapy code

Comment: are you sure your spider is raising any item ?

Comment: Yeah,There are outputs in the terminal

Comment: shouldn't it be [insert_one](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document)?